# Is there anything in Pandas similar to dplyr's 'list columns'

Tags: pandas, dplyr

I'm currently transitioning from R to Python in my data analysis, and there's one thing I haven't seen in any tutorials out there: is there anything in Pandas similar to dplyr's 'list columns' ?

Link to refence:
https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/how-to-work-with-list-columns/

Comment: Hi, it's not that. With dplyr, you can have a column (in a dataframe) that is composed by lists, in a way that each row in that column is a list. And in each of those lists you have dataframes.
Here's another link that explains what i'm refering to:
<https://dcl-prog.stanford.edu/list-columns.html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` will accept any object type, including lists, in an object type column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['genre']=['drama, comedy, action', 'romance, sci-fi, drama','horror']
df.genre = df.genre.str.split(', ')
print(df, '\n', df.genre.dtype, '\n', type(df.genre[0]))

# Output:

                      genre
0   [drama, comedy, action]
1  [romance, sci-fi, drama]
2                  [horror]
 object
 <class 'list'>
```

We can see that:

- `genre` is a column of lists.
- The `dtype` of the `genre` column is `object`
- The type of the first value of `genre` is `list`.

There are a number of `str` functions that work with lists.

For example:

```py
print(df.genre.str.join(' | '))

# Output:

0     drama | comedy | action
1    romance | sci-fi | drama
2                      horror
Name: genre, dtype: object
```

```py
print(df.genre.str[::2])

# Output:

0     [drama, action]
1    [romance, drama]
2            [horror]
Name: genre, dtype: object
```

Others can typically be done with an `apply` function if there isn't a built-in method:

```py
print(df.genre.apply(lambda x: max(x)))

# Output:

0     drama
1    sci-fi
2    horror
Name: genre, dtype: object
```

See the documentation for more... [pandas str functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html#)

---

As for nesting dataframes within one another, it is *possible* but, I believe it's considered an anti-pattern, and `pandas` will fight you the whole way there:

```
data = {'df1': df, 'df2': df}
df2 = pd.Series(data.values(), data.keys()).to_frame()
df2.columns = ['dfs']
print(df2)

# Output:

                                                   dfs
df1                        genre
0   [drama, comedy...
df2                        genre
0   [drama, comedy...
```

```
print(df2['dfs'][0])

# Output:

                      genre
0   [drama, comedy, action]
1  [romance, sci-fi, drama]
2                  [horror]
```

See:

- [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954520/pandas-dataframe-within-dataframe)
- [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950087/pandas-storing-a-dataframe-object-inside-another-dataframe-i-e-nested-datafram)

A possibly acceptable work around, would be storing them as `numpy` arrays:

```
df2 = df2.applymap(np.array)
print(df2)
print(df2['dfs'][0])

# Output:

                                                   dfs
df1  [[[drama, comedy, action]], [[romance, sci-fi,...
df2  [[[drama, comedy, action]], [[romance, sci-fi,...

array([[list(['drama', 'comedy', 'action'])],
       [list(['romance', 'sci-fi', 'drama'])],
       [list(['horror'])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, it was very clarifying. But can you have other dataframes in each row (the same way its done in R here: https://dcl-prog.stanford.edu/list-columns.html)?

Comment: @RafaelPeixoto See the last section of my answer, and the accompanying links.

Comment: @RafaelPeixoto Also see the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html?highlight=nested%20dataframes#dataframe)